# Read from database and based on that update another field

Tags: php, mysql

I am fairly new to PHP and mysql and need some help to select data from a MYSQL database field, and based on that update another field using a php script. I managed to piece together the PHP script that returns the URL of the first image result.

Note: There are multiple rows in the table

Is this possible?

The last word in this piece of script eg "ystervark" needs to be the contents from field 1.

```
get_url_contents('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=ystervark');  // I need this word 'ystervark' to be replaced by the contents of field1
```

This returns the first googled image url:

```
<?php

function get_url_contents($url) {
    $crl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)');
    curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);

    $ret = curl_exec($crl);
    curl_close($crl);
    return $ret;
}

$json = get_url_contents('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=ystervark');  // I need this word 'ystervark' to be replaced by the contents of field1

$data = json_decode($json);

foreach ($data->responseData->results as $result) {
    $results[] = array('url' => $result->url, 'alt' => $result->title);
}

//print_r($results);


?>

<?php foreach($results as $image):
?>
    <?php echo ($image['url']);?></br> // This result needs to be updated to field2
<?php
    break;
?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Then the result from the code needs to be updated/inserted into field 2

```
<?php echo ($image['url']);?></br> // This result needs to be updated to field2
```

Thank you.

Comment: Where is your MySQL?

Comment: Hi, What do you mean where is my mymql? the database is on a network pc, I do have remote access.

Comment: You do not show how you're selecting data from MySQL so your question is unclear.

Comment: Sorry for just the links, but i got my script from here:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp